# How many people has Jim killed in Under the Dome?

Tags: character, under-the-dome

How many people has Jim killed in *[Under the Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome_(TV_series))*? This is a serious question, as I'm starting to wonder if Jim is a greater threat to humanity than the dome and what's inside it.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikia of the character Jim](http://underthedome.wikia.com/wiki/James_Rennie_Sr._(TV_Series)), he has killed 18 people directly and one indirectly. You can see it in the character detail in the side section.

> Killed Victims: 18 killed
>
> 1 indirectly killed

You can also see the list of killed victims there.

> Lester Coggins (pushed his head to the Dome; hearing aid exploded)
>
> Boomer Platt (killed in an explosion of a propane tank)
>
> Agatha Seagrave (caused; drowned)
>
> Maxine Seagrave (shot once)
>
> Otto Aguilar (shot once)
>
> Dorothy "Dodee" Weaver (fatally shot in the chest)
>
> Lyle Chumley (fatally stabbed in the chest)
>
> Philip "Phil" Bushey (indirectly; jumped off a cliff after Big Jim closed the path to Zenith)
>
> Rebecca Pine (bludgeoned to death)
>
> Andrea Grinnell (fatally shot in the head)
>
> Marston (throat slashed)
>
> Carolyn Hill (unknowingly; crushed by falling debris)
>
> Hektor Martin (shot in the head)
>
> Kyle Lee (bludgeoned to death with a trophy)
>
> James "Junior" Rennie (stabbed in the heart in self-defense)
>
> 3 unnamed Chester's Mill residents (1 man stabbed in the back and 2 men sliced in their necks)
>
> 2 unnamed farmers (both shot while fighting for the well on Ollie's side)